# Design to dynamically apply filters on list of products

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I need some of your inputs in deciding a right approach in following case.

I am currently working on a ecommerce application (An online shopping website). Here, on homepage of application, I have to display a list of products available in shop. The end user has a facility of applying filters (include/exclude) to products list so that only the products satisfying the applied filter will be displayed.

So, my question is regarding the correct design for applying these filter on products in Java layer. Please note I keep all the data in-memory (hashmap) at Java layer. I just want to apply filters that are passed as an input from UI on this in-memory data store and return back the filtered results.

**Backend:** Java application hosted on Tomcat. This application has a periodic thread running that reads/refreshes product data from file system every 30 seconds and keeps it in-memory of java process.

**Frontend:** React application hosted on Nginx. Makes rest calls to backend server to fetch the data.

**Approaches I considered:**

Create a class called "FilteredProducts" that has attribute (say filtering criteria). Have different implementations for each possible filtering criteria using strategy pattern and apply the filtering criteria on products based on filtering criteria that is passed as an input.

Can anyone please guide me, if there is any recommended way to handle this requirement? Any input is highly appreciated. Please let me know if more information is required in this context.

Comment: it would be nice to see your attempts and thoughts on it

Comment: Yes also please share with us the details of your implementation. What kind of technologies you use for the UI, what kind for the backend etc etc.

Comment: This question is too broad--if it gets taken down, try researching and making a stab at it, then ask a more specific question. The only possible answers to this are going to be vague guesswork/opinion-based or someone will write the entire application for you.

Comment: Updated the question with more details.

Answer (score -1):

You could create an interface or abstract class filter and for each filter element you could create a specific class that implements or extends the interdace/superclass.
Then you could implement a matches method and check, which articles meet the criterias (e.g.:)

```
public interface FilterCriteria() {
 public List<ShopElement> getMatchedProducts(int minPrice, int maxPrice);
}

public class PriceFilterCriteria implements FilterCriteria() {
  @Override
  public List<ShopElement> getMatchedProducts(int minPrice, int maxPrice) {
    List<ShopElement> matchedProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    foreach(ShopElement se : YourDataSource.getAllElements() ) {
         if(se.getPrice() > minPrice && se.getPrice() < maxPrice) {
         matchedProducts.add(se);
         } 
     }  
  }
}
```

This pattern is really called filter pattern.
Your strategy pattern approach may work, but i think it is some kind of 'wrong-placed' in this context, because i think strategie pattern is mostly for changing concrete implementations within a client and not for combining various, cross-cutting filters.

Comment: public List<ShopElement> getMatchedProducts(int minPrice, int maxPrice)

This method in an interface binds interface to be implemented by only those filter classes that has something called as price. What if there is a filter called as size or there is a filter called as brand?

Comment: this is just an approach. you could also inject your filter into a method. so you could do getMatchedProucts(Filter filter) and then call on the concrete filter